# City states declaring war

Tags: civilization-5

I am in the middle of a game where I am the Chinese, so I am obviously going to play aggressively.

I have declared war on two city states, and in turn, I have had about 6 more declare war on me.

1. Are city states a threat when they
   declare war?
2. Do city states even leave their
   borders?
3. What are the negative effects of
   them doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. They can be significant threats, especially if there are enough of them against you. The game always ensures that their units are upgraded to the same level as the player with the highest tech advantage, and they are able to produce units pretty regularly.
2. They will leave their borders and are even capable of taking over enemy cities, although such an occurrence is infrequent.
3. Nation states can get to a point where they permanently declare war on you. This makes the diplomatic victory a lot more difficult since you can't rely on their votes. You also lose out on resource trading potential, which can be quite profitable.

Answer (score 1):

I've played with city states as allies, and they've sent troops to join my forces when attacking cities of mutual enemies close to them.

I expect the same will be true when you are attacked, which could well tip the balance against you.

Also bear in mind that in they're allied to another nation against you, that they will be providing units, resources, and culture to them (fun times).